# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer not working on orientation change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a added a pan gesture recogniser for screen edge (left) edge. It is working well in portrait mode but in landscape orientation its not working.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    //Pan Gesture for dragging Screen Edge
    let panGestureFromScreenEdge = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panFromSide(sender:)))
    panGestureFromScreenEdge.edges = .left
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureFromScreenEdge)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add gesture recognizers to the window. The highest view with which you should be concerned is the window's `rootViewController!.view`. Even better, if this is view controller code, add it to `self.view`.